# MAMP Pro 5.0.3 SSL Failure

Tags: ssl, mamp-pro

All sites work fine when SSL is not enabled. Once I enable it, it fails...

I installed MAMP Pro 5.0.3 today hoping that might change things. Tried SSL again, got a failure and this message from the log:

[Tue Aug 07 16:14:53 2018] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 10.20.1.10:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on here? (Oh, and how to fix it....) Thanks in advance...